# How to get BIOS time using assembly ?

Tags: c, time, interrupt, bios

I am implementing a small operating system from scratch for educational purpose.
Now, I want to get the BIOS time using assembly. I have searched a lot for this but couldn't find any code example to do so.
I would be really grateful , if anybody could provide any reference or code examples or anything related to this.

Comment: The architecture is i386

Answer (score 2):

See [time-of-day interrupt 1a documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/liangweiqiang/Home/e5006/e5006classnote/jumptiming/int1ahclockservice).  So try:

```
mov ah, 0
int 01ah
```

The number of clock ticks since midnight will be returned in `cx:dx`.  There are `0x1800B0` clock ticks per day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much will this help you, but I would recommend you to start reading the articles at osdev.org .You may find something related at http://wiki.osdev.org/RTC and http://wiki.osdev.org/CMOS#Getting_Current_Date_and_Time_from_RTC .I guess your OS will be 16 bit, so you can access the BIOS interrupts, you may find some helpful answers on their forum also. I had also written a very basic 32bit OS (it did not include any clock), but if you want to see the source code, feel free: http://os.sourcecodeplease.net/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably wrong now, but it was an interupt back in the i386 days. I want to say it was 11h.